# DataProtectionProvider.UnprotectAsync(IBuffer) throws a ASN-1 error

Tags: c#, uwp

When I try to run this code I'll get an "ASN1 - value is to great. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80093104)" error on the "UnprotectAsync" call and I cannot understand why.

The protectedText is like 850bytes bit, its tiny....

```
var protectedText = File.ReadAllBytes(this.userDataPath);
string unprotectedText = await this.UnprotectStringAsync(protectedText.AsBuffer());

private async Task<String> UnprotectStringAsync(IBuffer buffProtected)
{
    DataProtectionProvider Provider = new DataProtectionProvider();

    IBuffer buffUnprotected = await Provider.UnprotectAsync(buffProtected);

    String strClearText = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, 
    buffUnprotected);

    return strClearText;
}
```

Comment: Please check document remark [part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.dataprotection.dataprotectionprovider.unprotectasync?view=winrt-19041#remarks). *For security descriptors and SDDL strings, you must set the enterprise authentication capability in the manifest.*  Have you used  security descriptors or  SDDL strings?

Comment: I used the "LOCAL=user"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I dont know what I did wrong, I deleted the method and rewrote it. Now it works.